# React onBlur not affecting the whole form element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my react app, I have a form with an input and a Text area inside. When I click on the text area it expands and shows the input and the add button.
Currently, when I try to click on the input the `handleOnBlur` function gets called. I only want to call it when its outside the form. Please let me know if someone knows how to fix this.

```js
function handleFocusIn() {
    setExpand((prevValue) => {
      return {
        ...prevValue,
        showInput: true,
        rows: 3,
      };
    });
  }

  function handleOnBlur(event) {
    console.log(event.target.name);

    setExpand((prevValue) => {
      return {
        ...prevValue,
        showInput: false,
        rows: 1,
      };
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form
        onFocus={handleFocusIn}
        onBlur={handleOnBlur}
        className="create-note"
      >
        {expand.showInput ? (
          <input
            name="title"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={note.title}
            placeholder="Title"
          />
        ) : null}

        <TextareaAutosize
          name="content"
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={note.content}
          placeholder="Take a note..."
          rows={expand.rows}
        />

        {expand.showInput ? (
          <Zoom in={true}>
            <Fab onClick={submitNote}>
              <AddIcon />
            </Fab>
          </Zoom>
        ) : null}
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you will use `onBlur` in the input field component instead of the form tag. This might not blur your input field, when you click on it.

Comment: I am using that as a compromise but with that `onBlur` doesnt work if I was focused on the textarea

Comment: If I am understanding you right, then what you want is that, every form element gets blurred out, but the one where you have clicked ? is it the case? @arinnie

Comment: I want it to hide the <input>, the button and make the text area have 1 row. Here's an [image](https://imgur.com/a/aIbOJ8U) of my app. But the onBlur gets activated in the when clicked in the blue areas. I only want it to activate when clicked outside the white box and the button. @Mani